# How do I get my Azure C# function app to return json?

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I have a function app which I run locally to test and all is fine

```
http://localhost:9999/api/DataFunction
```

This returns a json string no problem.

However when I publish and connect to the url from Azure I just get the "**Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running**" page.

```
https://datafunctionxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/
```

The app has hard coded data as I am new to Function Apps and this was a test.

What have I missed, do I need to do something else?
I published from VS2022 to Azure with all the default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried appending `api/DataFunction` on to the end of your URI:

`https://datafunctionxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Datafunction`

If you are using function level authentication then you will also have an authentication key as a query string.

`https://datafunctionxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Datafunction&code=<keyhere>`

You can obtain this from the Azure Portal

[image: Get function URL]

Comment: yep, I get a 401 error. I'm using Chrome Dev tools and I can see no errors reported ((failed)net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE ) :(

Comment: I've updated my original answer above to include the function authentication which is the default option when using the templates included with VSCode or the functions CLI

Comment: my portal looks a little bit different but I dug around and found it :)

Comment: Awesome stuff. Hope you enjoy playing with functions as much as I do.